# How to parse a text file with c#?

Tags: c#, parsing

How do I parse a Textfile like:

> {:block1:}
>
> %param1%= value1
>
> %param2% = value2
>
> %paramn% =valuen
>
> {:block2:}
>
> 1st html - sourcecode Just copy 1:1
>
> {:block3:}
>
> 2nd html - sourcecode Just copy 1:1
> ...{:block4:}
>
> 3rd html - sourcecode Just copy 1:1

I would like to convert data to a XmlDocument.
Blocks are identified by {::} and params are identified by %%=

Thanx a lot.

What I'm looking for is more an idea but complete code. I have found many examples reading ini-files using RegEx and a TextReader to get some lines. The problem is: It's possible, that more than one {:block:} is within a line. There are so many whitespaces, linebreaks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that more than one {:block:} can appear within a line, could you replace every "{" with a "\r\n{" to guarantee that every block is in its own line?  (In other words, replace every "{" with a "newline{" )  would the extra spaces cause a problem?  Otherwise, you could write a Regex expression to identify only those blocks where you need to enter a linebreak.

The whitespaces and line breaks are both handled with the Regex escape character \s.  A common way to use \s in Regex is either as "\s+" or "\s*", depending on whether whitespace is optional or necessary.

It would also help if you were more specific about particular problems.

Comment: I split after {:xxx:} and all linebreaks and so on will be replaced by ";" and so I found all sections and params. It works really great. Thanks.